# Unable to drop database in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, drop-table

I have created a sample database earlier and now I want to delete that database, but it is not getting deleted. I searched online but I didn't find any solution which is working.

Using T-SQL, I tried:

```
USE [Sample]

ALTER DATABASE [Sample]
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO

DROP DATABASE [Sample]
```

Using the GUI, I am getting this below error:

[image]

I closed existing connection then also this is happening and this is my local machine. Please help me here!

Comment: just test DROP DATABASE Sample;

Comment: this statement not working?

Comment: @Hasan Fathi. I tried that also, it didn't worked!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this code:

```
USE MASTER 
GO

ALTER DATABASE Sample 
SET multi_user WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO


ALTER DATABASE Sample
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO

DROP DATABASE Sample
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Close your SSMS , open a new instance and then try the following, Copy paste the whole thing into a new query window and execute at once:

```
USE [master];            
GO

ALTER DATABASE [Sample]   --<-- go back into Multi-user mode
SET MULTI_USER;
GO

ALTER DATABASE [Sample]   --<-- Will disconnect everyone 1st
SET SINGLE_USER              -- and will leave the database in single user mode
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO

USE [Sample];                -- quickly grab that single connection before any 
GO                           -- other process does

USE [master];                -- Connect to master db,  connection
GO                           -- This also means disconnect Sample DB 

DROP DATABASE [Sample]       -- At this point there should be no active connections
GO                           -- to this database and can be dropped
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to delete the Database (without coding)

- In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, Right-click the Database that you want to delete (In your case, Sample Database) and then Select **Properties**.
- Select the '**Options**' Page.
- Under the **other option**, Find the '**Restrict user**' option under '**State**'.
- Change it value **MULTI_USER** to **SINGLE_USER**
- Then Press **Okay** and Try again (Or right-click the database again and click **Delete**)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code should help.

```
ALTER DATABASE [dbname]
SET SINGLE_USER --or RESTRICTED_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
DROP DATABASE [dbname];
GO
```